# How to pass a List<dynamic> to a List<MyModel> from a JSON?

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, dart, json-deserialization

I have an app that retrieve data from an API, I receive the data as a List and when I print it I can see the data ok.

```
[
  {
    "1": "MaxMilyin",
    "2": "409733",
    "3": "1130794"
  },
  {
    "1": "HippopotamusRex",
    "2": "346742",
    "3": "1204932"
  },
  ...
]
```

When I try to pass the list to a list of my model I only get:

```
   [Instance of 'TopTenUsersModel', Instance of 'TopTenUsersModel', ...]
```

This is my model class, I used this [site](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) to generate the class:

```
class TopTenUsersModel {

  String s1;
  String s2;
  String s3;

  TopTenUsersModel({this.s1, this.s2, this.s3});

  TopTenUsersModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    s1 = json['1'];
    s2 = json['2'];
    s3 = json['3'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['1'] = this.s1;
    data['2'] = this.s2;
    data['3'] = this.s3;
    return data;
  }
}
```

This is the method that I return the data as my model.

```
static Future<List<TopTenUsersModel>> getTopTenUsers() async{

    try{

      print("INICIANDO CONEXÃO COM A API...");

      var response = await client.get(
        Constants.BASE_URL + Constants.getTopTenUsers + Constants.AUTH
      );

      //print("PRINT RESPONSE NETWORK UTIL: ${response.body}");

      // Here I can see the data ok!

      List<dynamic> list = json.decode(response.body) as List;

      // Here I get 'Instance of 'TopTenUsersModel''

      return (json.decode(response.body) as List)
          .map((item) => TopTenUsersModel.fromJson(item))
          .toList();

    } on SocketException catch (e){
        throw (e.message);
    } finally {
      client.close();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I can't figure out what you want ewactly. it seems you've tried to print a list of TopTenUsersModel in tou console.You have to know that there is no way to directly print Dart object in your console. Please implement a toSting method in your TopTenUsersModel class then you can print any instance of your TopTenUsersModel

Comment: take a look to [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51). Check the "JSON structure #5 : List of maps" section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be implement below ways

**Model class**

```
  class TopTenUsersModelResponse {
  final List<TopTenUsersModel> list;

  TopTenUsersModelResponse({
    this.list,
  });

  factory TopTenUsersModelResponse.fromJson(List<dynamic> parsedJson) {
    List<TopTenUsersModel> list = new List<TopTenUsersModel>();
    list = parsedJson.map((i) => TopTenUsersModel.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return new TopTenUsersModelResponse(list: list);
  }
}
```

replace

```
 List<dynamic> list = json.decode(response.body) as List;

      // Here I get 'Instance of 'TopTenUsersModel''

      return (json.decode(response.body) as List)
          .map((item) => TopTenUsersModel.fromJson(item))
          .toList();
```

by

```
final List parsed = json.decode(response.body);
List<TopTenUsersModel> responseModelList = new TopTenUsersModelResponse.fromJson(parsed).list;
```

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for a solution to a problem of mine, extracting a dynamic list from a JSON via REST API. I finally read your post and, thanks to this line of code, I solved the problem.

```
  return (json.decode(response.body) as List)
      .map((item) => TopTenUsersModel.fromJson(item))
      .toList();
```

Comment: This isn't an answer; gratitude can be expressed as a comment.